# OpenVPN Cloud connection issues

Tags: openvpn

So, what I'm trying to achieve is to gain remote access to a Raspberry Pi 4 from a Windows 10 computer using OpenVPN Cloud. The Windows Computer is defined on the "Users" section and assigned the IPV4 address "100.96.1.3".

In the case of the Raspberry Pi you need to create a host which is given a subnet IP address "100.96.1.16/24". Then you create a connector which will produce the necessary configuration to allow the Raspberry PI access to the VPN Network with an IP address "100.96.1.18".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpgHW.png)

The problem I'm finding with this, is that I can ping and access my computer from the Raspberry Pi, but I can´t access nor ping my Raspberry from the computer's side. I've checked if ssh is enabled in the Raspberry Pi, I created some rules to allow all traffic coming from and to OpenVPN Cloud but not much has changed.

I've also talked to support and they say routing seems to be fine also. If somebody can help me out it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly I only had to deactivate the NAT function for it to work.